# Syntax error in content type case statement

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, padrino

This is my code in my Padrino application and I can't figure out what line or bug it is. The error message is "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end expecting $end"

```
get :index, :provides => [:html, :json] do
    @title = "Restaurants"
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all

    case content_type
      when :json
        render @restaurants
      else
        render 'restaurants/index'
      end
    end
  end
```

Could you please point out my mistake and also suggest how I might debug it in future? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one spare `end` keyword. 
You should remove one.

There is a little mess with indentation in your code. Keeping right indentation helps a lot in avoiding such errors. I would suggest to indent your code like this:

```
get :index, :provides => [:html, :json] do
  @title = "Restaurants"
  @restaurants = Restaurant.all

  case content_type
  when :json
    render @restaurants
  else
    render 'restaurants/index'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an `end` too much.

Be more careful with your code indentation and this will never be a problem. Example on how it would look in Vim under. I just used <kbd>=G</kbd> and it aligned it for me. Additionaly, it'll only highlight the correct use of `end`. Your favorite editor of choice *should* have this functionality too. If not, switch.

[image]

Comment: Great tip! I use Vim too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
get :index, :provides => [:html, :json] do
    @title = "Restaurants"
    @restaurants = Restaurant.all

    case content_type
      when :json
        render @restaurants
      else
        render 'restaurants/index'
      end

  end
```